# How to get a return value from a function without assigning values to its variables in c++

Tags: c++, function, return-value

I have a function Pr which returns a value in the Shadowing class.

```
double Shadowing::Pr(PacketStamp *t, PacketStamp *r, WirelessPhy *ifp)
{
    ----
    ---
    return Pr;
}
```

All the pointers *t,*r,*ifp are taken from the included header files.
Now I need to get the Pr value in another c++  file by assigning the function to a variable, say rpower. 
rpower = Shadowing::Pr( );
But the problem is, some particular values are to be given for the function to return Pr. I'm not able to figure out how to do that, without giving values, as they're taken dynamically.
 I'm a newbie working on c++ for my project work. It'd be of great help if someone could help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

If t, r, and ifp are static values in the header, then they do not need to be parameters to the function. You can just access them in the code. On the other hand, the dynamically acquired values need to be passed to the function as parameters in order to let Pr have access to them

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So you are saying, I can give rpower = Shadowing::Pr(PacketStamp *t, PacketStamp *r, WirelessPhy *ifp ) as it is in the function, in order to assign Pr to rpower, is it so?